# Conveying 'burn the midnight oil'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

L'expression "burn the midnight oil" signifie travailler tard dans la nuit, souvent jusqu'à une heure avancée. Cela implique de rester éveillé tard dans la nuit pour accomplir une tâche, souvent liée aux études ou à des responsabilités professionnelles.
Voir : https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burn_the_midnight_oil

> John had to burn the midnight oil to finish the project before the deadline.

> John a dû veiller tard dans la nuit pour terminer le projet avant la date limite.

Y a-t-il des expressions idiomatiques pour rendre ce sens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Une expression courante est : [Ne pas compter ses heures](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_pas_compter_ses_heures)

> *John n'a pas compté ses heures pour terminer le projet avant la date limite.*

Note that this expression usually implies the person is working on a paid job so that normally rules out a student.

Answer (score 2):

> Travailler jusqu'au petit matin. ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&srchtxt=BURN%20MIDNIGHT%20OIL))

Je trouve le calque « ...jusqu'aux petites heures du matin » (*in the small hours of the morning*) plus idiomatique mais l'emploi est critiqué.

Answer (score 1):

(**EDIT**)

Une expressions idiomatique que j'ai trouvée (pas exactement le sens de l'expression anglaise mais du sens voisin)

> Travailler comme un forçat (source [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/for%C3%A7at)).

En ce qui concerne les études j'ai trouvé le verbe *bûcher* (source: [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/b%C3%BBcher/11592#:%7E:text=%C3%89tudier%20avec%20%C3%A9nergie%20une%20discipline,sans%20rel%C3%A2che%20%3A%20B%C3%BBcher%20les%20math%C3%A9matiques.)).

Comment: Feel free to correct me or modify my answer.

Comment: Une source pour *rumer* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Happy New Year. I wrote the initial answer using my mobile phone. I've just made some corrections. I hope it is better. It was not 'rumer dur' but 'ramer dur'. Sorry for the misprint. Googling more I found that ramer does not have the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks, Happy New Year too! I suspected it was *ramer* but as you found out, it means sth different; to struggle unefficiently.

Comment: @jlliagre: Thanks! Is it ok my answer now?

Comment: Yes, it is.+1 :-)