# Elucubrer vs elucubrate

Tags: anglais, étymologie, évolution

Trying to find ways to convey in French the English idiom '[burn the midnight oil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54112/conveying-burn-the-midnight-oil)', I stumbled upon these words, 'elucubrate' and 'élucubrer,' and found their meanings to be a bit different.

In English, 'elucubrate' means to work studiously at night or to study, almost like 'burning the midnight oil.' Check it out on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elucubrate).

On the flip side, in French, 'élucubrer' has this literary sense of producing extravagant and unreasonable reflections. You can read more about it on [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9lucubrer).

Note, however, that the TLFi definition is quite different and closer to the original meaning: Composer un ouvrage péniblement et au prix de longues recherches. See [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9lucubrer).

I'm curious about the divergence in meaning in French. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le TLFi fait précéder la définition de « Iron. » pour *ironique*, et [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E0819) y ajoute « péjoratif » pour son sens aujourd'hui et l'emploi est noté comme « rare » ; [Robert en ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/elucubrer) ajoute *littéraire*. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu et le mot *élucubrations* au pluriel est beaucoup plus usuel. Le sens vieilli/[étymologique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9lucubrer) (attesté en 1594/DHLF) s'est perdu et le sens péjoratif s'y est substitué au début du 19e (1835/DHLF) :

> La nature expressive du mot a certainement joué, ainsi que des
> paronymies lointaines (*calembredaine*, *emberlificoter*, par
> exemple).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey,
> Robert, 2011 « élucubration » ]